# GetFieldByDisplayName error in CAML query

Tags: 2010, caml-query, visual-web-part, spgridview

I'm developing a web-part for SharePoint 2010.

I've to sort a `SPGridView` so I use `SortExpression`.

I execute a CAML query in this way and then I bind data to `SPGridView`:

```
            SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
            query.RowLimit = 30;
            query.Query = "<OrderBy><FieldRef Name=\"" + sortColumn + "\" Ascending=\"" + sortDir + "\" /></OrderBy>";
            query.ViewFields = "<FieldRef Name=\"Title\" />" +
                               "<FieldRef Name=\"DocIcon\" />" +
                               "<FieldRef Name=\"Ragione_x0020_Sociale\" />" +
                               "<FieldRef Name=\"Tipo_x0020_Protocollo\" />" +
                               "<FieldRef Name=\"Data_x0020_Protocollo\" />" +
                               "<FieldRef Name=\"Formato_x0020_Documento\" />" +
                               "<FieldRef Name=\"Utilizzatore_x0020_Interno\" />" +
                               "<FieldRef Name=\"Note\" />" +
                               "<FieldRef Name=\"Descrizione\" />";

            //query.QueryThrottleMode = SPQueryThrottleOption.Override;
            string listName = "Protocolli";
            SPList list = SPContext.Current.Web.Lists[listName];
            //list.EnableThrottling = false;

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(pagingInfo))
            {
                SPListItemCollectionPosition position = new SPListItemCollectionPosition(pagingInfo);
                query.ListItemCollectionPosition = position;
            }

            SPListItemCollection collection = list.GetItems(query);
            grdProtocolli.DataSource = collection.GetDataTable();

            grdProtocolli.PagerTemplate = null;  // Must be called after Controls.Add(oGrid)
            grdProtocolli.DataBind();
```

`sortColumn` is:

```
if (ViewState["SortExpression"] == null)
            {
                sortColumn = "Data_x0020_Protocollo";
            }
            else
            {
                sortColumn = ViewState["SortExpression"].ToString();
            }
```

`Data_x0020_Protocollo` is a field that currently exists.

Now, trying to execute my web-part I receive this error:

> 0x0AB0 SharePoint Foundation   Runtime tkau    Unexpected  System.ArgumentException: Impossibile trovare un campo con il nome "Data_x0020_Protocollo".
>           at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldCollection.GetFieldByDisplayName(String strDisplayName, Boolean bThrowException)
>
> "Impossibile trovare un campo con il nome..." is translated like "Impossible to find a field with name"

If I use the display name `Data Protocollo` I don't get the error anymore (and I can see the `GridView`), but sorting is not working.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things.

1. You need to handle OnSorting event and manually sort the DataTable. Then put the datatable back into ViewState
2. You should use DisplayName

Pseudo Code

```
protected void grdProtocolli_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)  
{  
    string sortingDirection = //LOGIC TO SET DIRECTION

    //direction is the public property
    if (direction == SortDirection.Ascending)  
    {  
        direction = SortDirection.Descending;  
        sortingDirection = "Desc";
    }  
    else  
    {  
        direction = SortDirection.Ascending;  
        sortingDirection = "Asc";         
    }  

    DataView sortedView = //Get DataView from DataTable.. You might need to read it from either ViewState or directly from the Grid View Control
    sortedView.Sort = e.SortExpression + " " + sortingDirection;  
    Session["Next"] = sortedView;  
    grdProtocolli.DataSource = sortedView;  
    grdProtocolli.DataBind();  
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Amal Hashim. This is my OnSorting event http://pastebin.com/fcQFxHkc I don't think to have understood well the "put the datatable back into ViewState". Could you please provide an example?

Comment: @Pepozzo see my updated answer. The code is not tested, but it will give you the general idea.